# "Жду праздники"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "жду праздников" или "жду праздники"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь «Русское управление» фиксирует как нормативные оба варианта. При этом родительный падеж в сочетании с глаголом *ждать* придаёт высказыванию оттенок неопределённости ('жду каких-то/каких угодно праздников'), а винительный – определённости ('жду конкретные праздники').